# while running expo manage react native I am getting RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly linked

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, google-oauth

Android Bundling complete 3356ms
ERROR  RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly linked. Please read the readme, setup and troubleshooting instructions carefully or try manual linking.
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'SIGN_IN_CANCELLED' of null, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I tried npx run android but I getting same error can some help me